# Can Windows Phone 8 and Android connect over Wifi Direct?

Tags: android, windows-phone, windows-phone-8, wifi-direct

I am developing a multi-platform multi-player game app and want to be able to connect the players to each other. To avoid possible latency issues (and the need for a server) I would like to connect the players to each other using Wifi Direct.

It appears that Windows Phone 8 and Android both now support WiFi Direct but can they be made to connect to each other?

Ideally I would want the player to be able to decide whether they are hosting or joining a game and then accept connections or see a list of players hosting a game accordingly. (Game joiners wouldn't be able to see each other)

Android has some documentation here https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd-wifi-direct.html which looks like what I need.

Windows Phone has some documentation here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.proximity.peerfinder but I am still not sure whether it supports Wifi Direct (rather than only bluetooth) and it doesn't look like it will allow me to a host a network service.

Even if Windows Phone DOES support WiFi Direct, is it compatible with Android's implementation?

Comment: Never heard of "wifi direct(TM)" but I'm pretty sure both platforms do UDP broadcast, so it should be possible to write your own discovery protocol.

Comment: @asveikau the benefit of Wifi Direct is that it is peer to peer so that  I wouldn't have to rely on the phones being attached to the same multicast enabled router/switch. But as you suggest it would be possible to do this to support my gaming scenario. Here is a windows phone example http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Multicast-Sockets-Sample-51190c11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows Phone 8 doesn't support WiFi direct communication from the WP8 SDK.

Comment: Thanks Justin, as this is from you I can take this to be definitely true. I'm sure my 920 was showing Windows.Networking.Proximity.PeerFinder.SupportedDiscoveryTypes &  Windows.Networking.Proximity.PeerDiscoveryTypes.Browse as true but I can't verify this as its had to go for a repair. I thought this would indicate that Wifi Direct could be used (judging from the rest of the example code). Is this the case and if so what is it really telling us? Thanks.

Comment: Soon as indicated here: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/3306284-support-for-wifi-direct